# Python, kivy error [CRITICAL][Video] unable to find any valuable video provider

Tags: python, video, kivy

I am using python27 and kivy 1.9.2. I installed everything reccomended including docutils, pygments pypivin32, sdl2, glew and gstreamer, but I still got this error.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\MCAT\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-02-14_18.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[WARNING] The 'fake' fullscreen option has been deprecated, use Window.borderless or the borderless Config option instead.
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.4459>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) HD Graphics>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.40 - Intel Build 9.17.10.4459>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <No errors.>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <No errors.>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] program: <No errors.>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[CRITICAL] [Video       ] Unable to find any valuable Video provider.
```

I'm not able use Video or VideoPlayer because I still get error:

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file join.png
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file join.avi
```

Anybody know why unable to find video provider (despite gstreamer 0.1.12 installed)? 
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Which OS are you on? And how did you install kivy?

Comment: I am developing on Windows 10. I installed kivy via command line following these instructions [link](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) .

Comment: try removing using `pip uninstall kivy` and then reinstalling using `'pip install http://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Before you reinstall set this environment variable: `KIVY_WINDOW=sdl2`

Comment: I am not able to install kivy using 'pip install http://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip'. I am still getting this error:

Comment: creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\users\mcat\appdata\local\temp\pip-oqghrv-build\kivy\graphics
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\users\mcat\appdata\local\temp\pip-oqghrv-build\kivy\include -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\users\mcat\appdata\local\temp\pip-oqghrv-build\kivy\include -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcc:\users\mcat\appdata\local\temp\pip-oqghrv-build\kivy\graphics\opengl.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\users\mcat\appdata\local\temp\pip-oqghrv-build\kivy\graphics\opengl.obj
    opengl.c

Comment: c:\users\mcat\appdata\local\temp\pip-oqghrv-build\kivy\include\gl_redirect.h(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: You need http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you, but still now working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas. You could try posting an issue on kivy's github page

Comment: I will post it there, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Install PIL and Pillow, and report back

Comment: Hello adewale, I've already solved it, but thank you for your willingness.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install pygame`
it should fix your problem